# Delay Docker Swarm Replicas Reschedule when Node Restart

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I currently have a 3 node swarm mode cluster.  1 manager and 2 workers.  I have created a service with replicas of 20.  When running `docker service ps <service>`, I do see all replicas have been deployed evenly in 3 nodes.  I believe the default swarm placement strategy is `spread` instead of `binpack`.  That's all good.  The problem is when I restart one of the workers after some OS maintenance.  The node will take a while to reboot, but at this time, I do not want the services to reschedule to the other 2 nodes because I know the restarted node will soon come back online.  Is there a way to delay swarm to reschedule replicas after a node reboot or failure?  I want to give it more time before confirming the node is really failed, like maybe 5 minutes or so.

Docker version  `20.10.7`